# How to calculate return instructions after a period of the program (based on the aspect of computer hardware)

Tags: performancecounter, perf

I've been working on rop recently. When using perf to count hardware information, I want to measure the number of return instructions executed by a given piece of code. But the perf interface only provides branch instructions.

Comment: "Brunch" is probably "branch", but what is "rop"?

Comment: @molbdnilo: possibly Return-Oriented Programming = using a buffer overflow to supply a chain of return addresses send execution to "gadgets" at known addresses.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming.  A special case of ROP is ret2reg to defeat stack ASLR by finding a `jmp esp` "gadget", but only if the stack is executable.  ([Why JMP ESP instead of directly jumping into the stack](//security.stackexchange.com/q/157478))

Comment: `ret` *is* a branch.  Are you sure you can't just count `ret` instructions in the full trace of the program you can reconstruct from intel-pt?  Or are you using counters like `br_inst_retired.all_branches`?

Comment: *only provides brunch instructions.* Oh, do they settle the pancake vs. waffle debate?  :P

Comment: Mmmm, brunch...

Comment: I'm sorry, I have corrected my mistake...

Answer (score 2):

If you're only x86 with a recent Intel CPU:

`perf list` on my Skylake shows there's a hardware counter for `br_inst_retired.near_return`.  That will count only `ret` instructions, not other branches.  But see erratum SKL091 for branch-instruction counters.

`perf stat -e instructions,br_inst_retired.near_return,...  ./a.out` may be what you're looking for.  Or maybe attaching `perf stat` to an already-running program, or maybe `-I 1000` to print accumulated counts over intervals.

But note that if you're looking for [ROP gadgets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming), you can find a `C3` opcode *inside* what normally decodes as some other instruction.  So restricting yourself only to `ret` instructions that actually run during the target program's normal execution is more limiting than it needs to be.

e.g. a 4-byte immediate might usefully decode as something + `ret` if you jump to the immediate.

Comment: The number of retired return instruction can be counted on the Pentium, NetBurst, Sandy Bridge, and later microarchitectures, and all Intel Atom microarchitectures (but the name of the event may be different). On the Intel Core, Core2, Nehalem, and Westmere, only executed returns can be counted (not necessarily retired). On the Pentium Pro and Pentium M, there are no events for specific types of branches. On many AMD processors, event 0xC8 can be used to count retired returns. In all the events above, only near returns are counted. There are no events for far returns only.

Comment: A A A!! Thank you for providing such useful information, I will have a deeper study.